# How to Generate PayPal Payment Link and send to payer Email?

Tags: php, paypal

I want to Paypal Payment link generator like show on below Image

[image]

In this form I want Admin fill Detail and send Mail to customer, and customer click email link and redirect to paypal for payment.

Comment: What is the issue here? Post your code!

Comment: Sorry, is this a design i created, i have no code,I want to in this type Paypal API code